# How to use stack widget inside a StaggeredGridView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview, flutter-layoutbuilder

[image: Before Adding stack widget]

[image: After Adding stack widget]om/cFMse.png

why images get weird size when i use stack widget inside StaggeredGridView.. When i remove the stack from the grid view the layout seems perfectly fine . am i using the layout in a wrong way?

```
new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                itemCount:model.hit.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return
                    Stack(
                     children: [
                       Container(
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.transparent,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35))),
                         child:
                         ClipRRect(
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35)),
                             child:FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                               placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: model.hit[index]['largeImageURL'],fit: BoxFit.cover,)

                         ),


                       )
                     ],
                    );

                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                  return new StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing a StackFit.expand argument to the Stack

```
return
    Stack(
       fit: StackFit.expand, /// <-- expand to the size of the parent constraint
       children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35))),
              child: ClipRRect(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35)),
                 child:FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                   placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: model.hit[index]['largeImageURL'],fit: BoxFit.cover,)
                 ),
             )
        ],
);
```